# Error: The called function should be payable

Tags: solidity

This is a common error and there are quite a few posts related to the error. However none of the solution seems working here when deploying a  `solidity 0.7` contract. Here is the constructor:

```
uint256 public value;  //in FYX
uint256 public feePercent; //ex, 125 is 1.25% as 125/10000
string public itemName;
uint256 public itemId;
address payable public seller;
address payable private feeAddress;  //address to take payment for transaction
address private contractDude;  //a address of contract keeping a list of user addresses
address private contractFEX;   //a ERC20 contract address

event itemForSale(address _seller, string _item, uint256 _id);

constructor (uint256 _value, string memory _itemName, uint256 _itemId, address _dudes, address _erc20, address payable _feeAdd, uint256 _feePercent) {  //seller deploys the contract
    bytes memory temp = bytes(_itemName);
    
    contractDude = _dudes;
    contractFEX = _erc20;
    feeAddress = _feeAdd;  //address receiving commission
    feePercent = _feePercent;
    require(mustBeDude(msg.sender), "Seller must be on chain"); //behind the address
    itemName = _itemName;
    itemId = _itemId;
    seller = msg.sender;
    value = SafeMath.add(0, _value);
    state = State.ForSale;
    
    emit itemForSale(msg.sender, _itemName, _itemId);   

}

function mustBeDude(address _add) view private returns (bool) {
    DudeOnChain _dudes = DudeOnChain(contractDude);
    return _dudes.isDude(_add);
}
```

Here is the error message when deploying:

```
VM error: revert. revert The transaction has been reverted to the initial state. Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.
```

The balance of the `seller` is zero when the contract is deployed. Tried to add `payable` to constructor and  add payable to address of `contractFEX`. Both didn't work.

Comment: Attach your full contract code please.

Comment: require(mustBeDude(msg.sender), "Seller must be on chain"); is the problem. The function mustBeDude has to access one of the address which hasn't been assigned in constructor and it throws error.